# GoogleSignIn on iOS won't show proper project name

Tags: ios, google-signin

I have GoogleSignIn integrated in the iOS app.
The name of my project in the `console.developers.google.com` was `xxxTest` and now I've changed it to simply `xxx` but when I sign in on iOS it says at the top `"Choose an account to continue to xxxTest"` instead of `xxx`. The change of the name was done days ago, so it shouldn't be a problem of cache.

I've changed the name from console.developers.google.com -> IAM & admin -> Settings

Is there another place I should change that or ... ?!

Any ideas ?